# Undefined control sequence error in output.bbl, how to find line?

Tags: overleaf, output

I got a bunch of errors in my overleaf document that look like this. Is there any way to find what line/area they are pointing to?

[image]

```
Undefined control sequence.

 
‪./output.bbl, 24‬
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more
<argument> ... Polarization}. \newblock {\em \prl 
                                                  }, 127(8):081101. 
l.24 
     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: line 24 of output.bbl has an undefined command `\prl`  , presumably because some entry in your `.bib` file uses that command without defining it.

Comment: I believe that red link in the top right corner of your image will take you to the error line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No clickling it does not help sadly, but I did find it when I searched for the \prl, which was the problem. Thanks! Idk why I didn't try that before..

Comment: The problem is obviously in the `.bib`file where the entry has `\prl` in the `journal` field. Check the entry and fix the field using `Phys. Rev. Lett.`

Comment: I had the same problem. Did you install **internet download manager** aka IDM? When using overleaf, make sure IDM is turned off first.